# How Do I delete .hta file after some seconds in bat files

Tags: html, batch-file, hta

I have this code :

```
@echo off
@title Login
echo ^<htm^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^<head^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^<link rel="stylesheet" link="style.css"^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^</head^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^<body^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^<p^>Hello!^</p^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^</body^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^</html^> >> "start.hta"
start.hta
```

But, I want when the 10 seconds ends, delete the "start.hta" and close the window.
How I do that?

Comment: I do not see any reason to write your HTA from within the batch file, _especially with all of those required escapes_, or not to close it directly from within the HTA itself. [Here's a quick example](https://ghostbin.com/paste/wb482) to show you a simpler method of doing this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the process id by incorporating some `powershell`, sleep 10 seconds and kill by process id.

```
@echo off
@title Login
echo ^<htm^> > "start.hta"
echo ^<head^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^<link rel="stylesheet" link="style.css"^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^</head^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^<body^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^<p^>Hello!^</p^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^</body^> >> "start.hta"
echo ^</html^> >> "start.hta"
for /f %%i in ('powershell "(Start-Process start.hta -passthru).ID"') do (
    timeout /t 10
    taskkill /F /PID %%i
    del "start.hta"
)
```

Comment: it was do job ! thanks.